# How to write should_not be_valid with expect syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am doing some tests while following codeschool course on `rspec` and I don't know how to write model validation for presence with `expect` syntax. If I write:

```
expect(user).should_not be_valid
```

`rspec` is telling me to use `expect` instead of `should_not`. But I can not find how to write the right expression to check validation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expect syntax should be

```
expect(user).not_to be_valid
```

Comment: I thought of that, but than I get this from rspec:
"Failure/Error: expect(user).not_to be_valid
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: is user an active record object? Can you write how you are defining it?